# Parallel processing in T - SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored Procedure which calls 35 `Inline table valued functions`(TVF's) one after the other.

All these inline TVF's return a table of calculated results from dbo.Match function.

Problem here is that despite of all appropriate indexes being in place,It takes quite long as next Inline TVF is called only when earlier one is done with its results. I want a way to execute these in parallel so that one does not have to wait for other to complete, May be by converting them to a procedure or any other envelope well suited for performance and parallel processing ?

Since `dbo.Match` function is common to all and calculating results based on parameters passed from statement in Inline TVF, I believe that would be synchronized if had a concept of `threads` in `sql`.
So, is there any available work around for problems like these to reduce the execution time ?

I have attached some piece of code to give a fair idea of what I am talking about :

```
      if @firstname is not null
      begin
      SELECT @constVal = FunctionWeight 
     FROM   dbo.FunctionWeights WHERE  FunctionWeights.FunctionId = 1;
      INSERT INTO #Temp2  
     (RowNumber,ValFromUser,ColumnName,ValFromFunc,FuncWeight,percentage) 
     SELECT RowNumber,@firstname,'firstname',PercentMatch,@constVal,PercentMatch * @constVal     FROM   dbo.MatchFirstName(@firstname, @checkbool)
    END 



if @Middlename is not null
  BEGIN
      SELECT @constVal = FunctionWeight FROM   dbo.FunctionWeights
 WHERE  FunctionWeights.FunctionId = 2;
  INSERT INTO #Temp2 (RowNumber,ValFromUser,ColumnName,ValFromFunc,FuncWeight,percentage)
      SELECT RowNumber, @MiddleName,'Middlename',PercentMatch, @constVal,PercentMatch * @constVal 
      FROM   dbo.MatchMiddleName(@MiddleName, @checkbool)
END
```

Comment: In sql you specify the result you want not how it should be fetched. If you want things to happen in parallel you need to stop using procedural logic (multiple statements, IF, WHILE etc) and write it based on sets, i.e. a single query. SQLServer will then run it in parallel if it determines it is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL, you tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*. You do this best by giving it the *entire* query to optimize and then let it work out how. So you'd do something like:

```
INSERT INTO #Temp2  
(RowNumber,ValFromUser,ColumnName,ValFromFunc,FuncWeight,percentage) 
SELECT RowNumber,@firstname,'firstname',
       PercentMatch,fw1.FunctionWeight,
       PercentMatch * fw1.FunctionWeight
FROM   dbo.FunctionWeights fw1
         CROSS JOIN
       dbo.MatchFirstName(@firstname, @checkbool) mfn
WHERE
     fw1.FunctionId = 1 AND
     @firstname is not null
UNION ALL
SELECT RowNumber, @MiddleName,'Middlename',
       PercentMatch, fw2.FunctionWeight,
       PercentMatch * fw2.FunctionWeight 
FROM   dbo.FunctionWeights fw2
         CROSS JOIN
       dbo.MatchMiddleName(@MiddleName, @checkbool) mmn
WHERE
     fw2.FunctionId = 2 AND
     @MiddleName IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
...
```

And so on - just keep adding each query in to this large `UNION ALL` query that combines all of the `SELECT`s, and try to replace `IF` logic with `WHERE` clause conditions.

For more complex queries where the parameters being passed to your functions depend on data from other tables, you might also need to look into using `CROSS APPLY` rather than `CROSS JOIN`, or more complex join conditions.

Comment: Wow :) I am so glad I learned this technique. I have one last simple question though, hope you answer this. Fields like FirstName, LastName and 33 more such fields are used as basis for searching like I mentioned above in question. However , creating an individual index for all of these would not be a great idea.So, is there anything you could suggest on that to avoid complete table scan ? @Damien_The_Unbelever

Comment: That was working well with couple of Union All's in query but as soon as goes beyond may be 20, performance is really affected. In fact with 35 parameters, it is working even slower than sequential approach. Any idea why is that ?

Comment: @Simran - If this is a generalized search routine (sorry, didn't pick up that that was the sort of context earlier) then you probably ought to read [Dynamic Search conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) by Erland Sommarskog. It covers a lot of detail.